# Access Update Statement: update according to current value

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am retrieving data from an external Access database. In this db, there is a column field '`recordTime`' which is formatted like this `dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM`, however the type for this field is string(don't ask me why not using date/time, I can't control this).

Now I would like to update this column field to make it as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss`, and probably still in string type. I use a query like this:

```
        UPDATE  table1
        SET     recordTime = Format(recordTime, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM');
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** In MS Access the default date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` so before reformatting you have to disambiguate date values by swapping `dd` and `mm` parts.

```
UPDATE Table1
  SET recordTime = FORMAT(MID(recordTime, 4, 2) + '/' + 
                          LEFT(recordTime, 2) + 
                          MID(recordTime, 6), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss')
 WHERE recordTime LIKE '##/##/####*'
```

If you were to have initially a value of

```
11/09/2013 04:00:00 PM
23/09/2013 02:00:00 PM
```

Then after update you'll get

```
2013-09-11 16:00:00
2013-09-23 14:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But sorry, your solution works well with `21/09/2013 04:00:00 PM`, but for `11/09/2013 04:00:00 PM`, I get `2013-11-09 16:00:00`, not `2013-09-11 16:00:00`. And this is something I wanna get rid of.

Comment: @Lyon Fair enough. You have to disambiguate date values first by swapping  `mm` and `dd` parts. See updated answer. Works on my machine.

Comment: Hi, @peterm, this is amazing. works like a charm. Thank you. However, it will do the update over and over again, is it possible to check if it's already updated before doing update?

Comment: I really don't want run it multiple times, that's why I ask. what I meant to say is that I would like to check if the column field is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM` or not. If yes, then I do update according to the statement you gave, otherwise, discard the update.

Comment: @Lyon By *...to be able to run it safely...* I meant exactly that - update only rows that match the pattern. In order to do that just add an appropriate `WHERE` clause. See updated answer.

Comment: Sure, @peterm, thank you for your patient. I just find another solution by using `case`. Thanks a lot, you saved my day.

Comment: I am sorry to trouble you again, the wildcard you provided in `WHERE` clause doesn't work well for me.

Comment: thank you for coming back. Update statement doesn't execute after I add `WHERE` clause as you said.

Comment: What do you mean *...doesn't execute...*? It doesn't update any rows or it produces an error? If the former than there is something wrong with your data (e.g. leading spaces). Try to play with simple `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE recordTime LIKE '##/##/####*'` and tweaking a pattern

Comment: It was the former just as you assumed. I checked bu there isn't any leading spaces. I tried with the `SELECT` statement, it still doesn't do anything. EOF return as true.

Answer (score 0):

Since your column is of type string you will have to work with substrings like (ms-access syntax, if you are working in the acces DB)

```
SET recordTime= mid(recordTime,7,4) & "-" & mid(recordTime,4,2) & "-" & left(recordTime,2) & " " & mid(recordTime,12,8)
```

MS-SQL syntax

```
SET recordTime= SUBSTRING(recordTime,7,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(recordTime,4,2)+'-'+ LEFT(recordTime,2)+' '+SUBSTRING(recordTime,12,8)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am working with Access. I tried your first SQL statement, nothing happens.

Comment: Well, "nothing" is not much indee .. ;-) Can you qualify what you get when do do for example `mid(recordTime,7,4)` ?

Comment: Hi, I got what I want from @peterm, thank you a lot for staying with me.